# Strip word from string

Tags: jquery

Probably a simple solution, but i don't get it working. I have a table with unique `id` attributes. Via buttons i can change the order of the table rows. When i click a button i want to receive the current order. This works fine with the code below except for the first value, which is `undefined`. How can i get rid of that undefined value?

```
    $("#saveOrder").click(function(e){
        var event = e || window.event;
        event.preventDefault();
        var t = "";
        $("#eventTable tr").each(function(){
            t += $(this).attr("id");
        });
        alert(t);
    });
```

I tried `t += $(this).attr("id").replace("undefined","");` but then the script won't `alert()` anything

Comment: Do you have a header row in your table that displays column names? I have a suspicion that is the case, and your header row doesnt have an Id.

Comment: Maurice, do you get any errors?

Comment: Damn yep, i have a table header at the top, with ofcourse, a table row! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `t += this.id || "";` This will substitute an empty string for undefined values.

Note that you can't use `replace` on `undefined`, since `undefined` isn't a string. You can convert a value `x` to a string representation via `String(x)` or `x+''`. However, this isn't necessary in this case.

**EDIT**

As Esailija points out, no need to create a jQuery object here.

Comment: I'd do `t += this.id || "";` but I guess there is not enough redundant jQuery in that...

Answer (score 1):

Try only selecting those rows with an id, like so:

```
$("#eventTable tr[id]").each(function(){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have a row without an `id` attribute. You could always skip it with a flag:

```
var t = "";
var first = true;
$("#eventTable tr").each(function(){
    if (!first) {
        t += $(this).attr("id");
    } else {
        first = false;
    }
});
```